# Salesforce Function returns Success 200 response locally, but the response body is empty and doesn't match my expected output structure

Tags: salesforce-functions

Is there anything I should be doing for code changes in my Salesforce Function to take effect? I am getting an empty response which doesn't match my expected output.

```
Using target-org myOrg login credential to initialize context
POST http://localhost:8080... 200
{
  "response": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After every code change to Salesforce Functions, make sure to Stop, Compile, Start and Run the function again. With the folder for function in question selected, open Command Palette/Terminal and do:

1. SFDX: Stop Function
2. `mvn compile`
3. SFDX: Start Function
4. `sf run function --function-url http://localhost:8080 --payload=@payload.json`